# Movファイルを開いて、ショートカットキーを実行する

Tags: windows-10, rpa

諸事情でQuicktimeを閉じられた環境で使用しています。
以下をUWSCで自動実行しようとしていますが、ファイルtest.movは開くものの
ショートカットキー操作がうまくQuicktimeに送れません。

**実現したい動作**

1. test.movをQuicktimePlayerで開く
2. Ctrl + L を実行
3. Crrl + F を実行

**書いたコード**

```
exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QuickTimePlayer.exe >C:\Users\hoge\Videos\test.mov")
SLEEP(10)
KBD(VK_CTRL, DOWN)
KBD(VK_L,CLICK, 100)
KBD(VK_CTRL, UP, 100)
SLEEP(1)
KBD(VK_CTRL, DOWN)
KBD(VK_F,CLICK, 100)
KBD(VK_CTRL, UP, 100)
```

**実際の結果**

test.movをQuicktimePlayerで開かれる
ショートカットキーがQuicktimeには送られない。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ショートカットキーを実行する際は、`KBD`ではなく、`SCKEY`を使うとうまくいきました。
修正して動いたコードは次のとおりです。

```
ID = exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QuickTimePlayer.exe C:\Users\hoge\Videos\test.mov")
id = GETID(GET_ACTIVE_WIN)
SLEEP(10)
SCKEY(ID,VK_CTRL,VK_L)
SCKEY(ID,VK_CTRL,VK_F)
```